# Sumar cantidades de una fila que tiene que ver con otra

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Buen dia,

Tengo la siguiente tabla de nombre "pedidos" donde id_registro_pedido es el numero del pedido como tal, el cliente aqui no interesa, el id_registro_usuario es el vendedor, y la fecha pues viene siendo la fecha del pedido

[image: tabla pedidos]

esta otra contiene los detalles de cada pedido, id_registro_detalle_pedido es la llave primaria pero no se usará, id_registro_pedido es el numero del pedido (tabla anterior) al cual pertenece el producto, id_registro_producto es el id del producto, valor_venta es el valor de venta del producto (aqui no interesa) y la cantidad, es la cantidad vendida del producto en ese pedido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es decir, aqui se guardan los productos, cantidades, valor venta que corresponden a los pedidos de la tabla anterior

Me gustaria saber si es posible con una consulta MySql, sumar el total de productos vendidos, por ejemplo de los productos con id=1 que esten en pedidos pero teniendo en cuenta que sean del usuario 2 entre un rango de fecha definido

He intentado esto con PHP pero solo me trae el total del primer producto bien y el resto en cero, quisiera saber si lo puedo hacer con una consulta solamente

```
    <?php
$consulta_pedidos = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM pedidos WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2020-02-08' AND '2020-02-09' AND id_registro_usuario = 2");
    //son 33 productos
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 33; $i++)
      {        
        $consulta_producto = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_registro_producto = $i");
        $array_producto = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_producto);
        $nombre_producto = $array_producto['nombre'];
        $cantidad_total_producto = 0;
        while($array_pedido = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_pedidos))
        {
          $id_registro_pedido=$array_pedido['id_registro_pedido'];         
          $consulta_detalle_pedido = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM detalle_pedidos WHERE id_registro_pedido = $id_registro_pedido AND id_registro_producto = $i");
            $array_detalle_pedido = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_detalle_pedido);
            
            $cantidad = $array_detalle_pedido['cantidad'];
            if($cantidad==""){$cantidad=0;}            
            $cantidad_total_producto=$cantidad_total_producto+$cantidad;            
        }
        $array_productos[] = array("nombre_producto" => $nombre_producto,
        "id_vendedor" => 2,
        "cantidad_total_producto" => $cantidad_total_producto);
        
      }    
      echo json_encode($array_productos);
    ?>
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo al respecto?

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta con lo que intenté con PHP pero no me funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo **con una sola consulta**, sería más o menos así:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(dp.cantidad) AS cantidad 
FROM pedidos p 
    INNER JOIN detalle_pedidos dp ON p.id_registro_pedido=dp.id_registro_pedido
WHERE 
    p.fecha BETWEEN '2020-02-08' AND '2020-02-09' 
    AND p.id_registro_usuario = 2 
    AND dp.id_registro_producto = 1;
```

Siendo que las tablas están relacionadas entre sí, puedes obtener no sólo una suma de la cantidad, puedes obtener cualquier registro o agrupación de cualquiera de las tablas, mediante una sola consulta. No necesitas tres consultas para esto, por algo las bases de datos son **relacionales**.

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias!!